# Parallelize a matmul-like matrix computation in Numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, tensor

Input `X` in shape `(n,n,m,m)`,

Output `Y` in shape `(n,n)`, where `Y[i,j]=∑_{k=1}^{n}{||X[i,j]-X[i,k]*X[k,j]||}`, with `*` denoting point-wise multiplication.

The silly `for` loop version is like:

```py
X = np.random.randint(1,10,size=(5,5,3,3))
n, _, m, _ = X.shape
Y = np.zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        cnt = 0.0
        X_ij = X[i, j] # in shape m x m
        for k in range(n):
            X_ikj = X[i, k] * X[k, j] # point-wise, in shape m x m
            cnt += np.sum(np.abs(X_ij - X_ikj))
        Y[i, j] = cnt
```

However I'd like to use a numpy parallel matrix computation. Exactly `Y[i,j]=∑_{k=1}^{n}{||X[i,j]-X[i,k]*X[k,j]||}` has a similar form with `matmul`. So in my view there are basically two points:

- How to `matmul` only along the first two dimensions, while keeping point-wise multiplication for the last two dimensions?
- `matmul` already summarize the `n-dim` vector `{X[i,k]*X[k,j]}_{k in [1,n]}`. However there is a function applied to each `X[i,k]*X[k,j]` before they're summarized.

Any possible idea is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you illustrate what you mean by 'a function is appiled to each `X[i,k]*X[k,j]` before they're summarized' and what is the relevance of this point in the problem?

Comment: @amzon-ex Say `f(X,i,k,j)=||X[i,j]-X[i,k]*X[k,j]||`. So it's impossible to directly apply `f` to each `X[i,j]` and then apply `matmul`.

Comment: If `X_ikj = np.matmul(X[i, k],X[k, j])` rather than point-wise, use `pairwise_consistency = 1 - np.abs(X[:, :, None] - np.matmul(X[:, None],X_t[None, ...])).sum((2, 3, 4)) / (2 * n * m)` in Quang's charming code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `broadcasting` but you need to swap the two axes with transpose:

```
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.randint(1,10,size=(5,5,3,3))

# transpose
# so X_t[j,k] == X[k,j]
X_t = X.transpose(1,0,2,3)

# output
# X_t[None,...]*X[:,None] is X[k,j] * X[i,k]
ret = np.abs(X[:,:,None] - X_t[None,...]*X[:,None]).sum((2,3,4))

# check
(ret==Y).all()
# True
```

Output (`ret`)

```
array([[1108, 1078,  709,  825,  752],
       [1163, 1185,  988, 1034,  910],
       [1043,  973,  828,  926,  706],
       [ 908,  927,  800, 1078,  765],
       [ 990,  905,  662,  864,  865]])
```